# I am getting a syntax error in postgreSQL that I am not able to solve

Tags: sql, postgresql

I keep getting a syntax error where the "and"s are and I keep not understanding why

```
SELECT  IDIntervento as _IDInterventoRif, IDCdc, IDCartella,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IDIntervento) as nInt
        FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi i
        WHERE (IDTipoRecord in('UTI','INT'))
            and i.IDCdc           =  inter.IDCdc
            and i.IDCartella      =  inter.IDCartella
            and i.UTIINGRESSODATA <  inter.UTIINGRESSODATA
            and i.IDIntervento    <> inter.IDIntervento 
     ) as _IDInterventoTipoN

FROM  cch.pats_cch_interventi inter
WHERE  (IDTipoRecord in('INT') OR IDTipoRecord IS NULL)
    and IDIntervento    <> ?
    and IDCdc           =  ?
    and IDCartella      =  ?
    and (DataIntervento <  ? 
            OR DataIntervento = ? and IDIntervento < ?)

ORDER BY IDCdc, IDCartella, UTIINGRESSODATA desc;
```

Comment: could you say what the syntax error is?

Comment: Break your statement up without the 'ands' and add them back in one at a time until it fails

Comment: `and IDIntervento    <> ?` (and the other similar ones) - if that's literally what your PG query is, then that's invalid. If the question mark is being replaced before the query executes, then show the query that is actually being executed. Otherwise that's the problem.

Comment: @Lucas the error is; "Error SQL [42601]: ERROR: syntax error by or near "and"

Comment: There is no straight syntax error on my version of postgres. What version are you using, and what client/library are you using? Is there any way you can output the "raw" SQL after your libraries have had their way with it?

Comment: I am using DBeaver 6.1.5